# GLSL How to show normals with Geometry shader?

Tags: opengl, glsl, geometry-shader

I have `vertex shader`

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 VertexPosition;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 VertexUV;
layout(location = 2) in vec3 VertexNormal;

out VS_GS_VERTEX
{
    vec2 UV;
    vec3 vs_worldpos;
    vec3 vs_normal;
} vertex_out;

uniform mat4 proj_matrix;
uniform mat4 model_matrix;

void main(void)
{
    gl_Normal = VertexNormal;
    gl_Position = proj_matrix * vec4(VertexPosition, 1.0);

    vertex_out.UV = VertexUV; //VertexPosition.xy;
    vertex_out.vs_worldpos = gl_Position.xyz;
    vertex_out.vs_normal = mat3(model_matrix) * gl_Normal;
}
```

and `fragment shader`

```
#version 330 core

in GS_FS_VERTEX
{
    vec2 UV;
    vec3 vs_worldpos;
    vec3 vs_normal;
} vertex_in;

// Values that stay constant for the whole mesh.
uniform sampler2D sampler0;
uniform sampler2D sampler1;
uniform sampler2D sampler2;
uniform sampler2D sampler3;
//uniform sampler2D alphamap0;
uniform sampler2D alphamap1;
uniform sampler2D alphamap2;
uniform sampler2D alphamap3;
uniform int tex_count;

uniform vec4 color_ambient = vec4(0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 1.0);
uniform vec4 color_diffuse = vec4(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 1.0);
//uniform vec4 color_specular = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
uniform vec4 color_specular = vec4(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.25);
uniform float shininess = 5.0f;
uniform vec3 light_position = vec3(12.0f, 32.0f, 560.0f);

void main(){
    vec3 light_direction = normalize(light_position - vertex_in.vs_worldpos);
    vec3 normal = normalize(vertex_in.vs_normal);
    vec3 half_vector = normalize(light_direction + normalize(vertex_in.vs_worldpos));
    float diffuse = max(0.0, dot(normal, light_direction));
    float specular = pow(max(0.0, dot(vertex_in.vs_normal, half_vector)), shininess);
    gl_FragColor = texture( sampler0, vertex_in.UV ) * color_ambient + diffuse * color_diffuse + specular * color_specular;

    // http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture_Combiners
    // GL_MODULATE = *
    // GL_INTERPOLATE Blend tex0 and tex1 based on a blending factor = mix(texel0, texel1, BlendFactor)
    // GL_INTERPOLATE Blend tex0 and tex1 based on alpha of tex0 = mix(texel0, texel1, texel0.a)
    // GL_ADD = clamp(texel0 + texel1, 0.0, 1.0)
    if (tex_count > 0){
        vec4 temp = texture( sampler1, vertex_in.UV );
        vec4 amap = texture( alphamap1, vertex_in.UV);
        gl_FragColor = mix(gl_FragColor, temp, amap.a);
    }
    if (tex_count > 1){
        vec4 temp = texture( sampler2, vertex_in.UV );
        vec4 amap = texture( alphamap2, vertex_in.UV);
        gl_FragColor = mix(gl_FragColor, temp, amap.a);
    }
    if (tex_count > 2){
        vec4 temp = texture( sampler3, vertex_in.UV );
        vec4 amap = texture( alphamap3, vertex_in.UV);
        gl_FragColor = mix(gl_FragColor, temp, amap.a);
    }
}
```

It takes indexed `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP` as input

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, tMt.vertex_buf_id[cx, cy]);
glVertexAttribPointer(VERTEX_LAYOUT_POSITION, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, pointer(0));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

{ chunk tex position }
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, chunkTexPositionBO);
glVertexAttribPointer(VERTEX_LAYOUT_TEX_UV, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, pointer(0));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, tMt.normal_buf_id[cx, cy]);
glVertexAttribPointer(VERTEX_LAYOUT_NORMAL, 3, GL_FLOAT, true, 0, pointer(0));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

{ index buffer }
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, chunkIndexBO);

for i := 0 to tMt.texCount - 1 do begin
  bt := tMt.texture_buf_id[cx, cy][i];
  if bt = nil then
     break;
  glUniform1i(proj_tex_count_loc, i);
  glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + i);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, bt.id);

  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

  if i > 0 then begin
    // this time, use blending:
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE4 + 1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tMt.alphamaps[cx, cy][i - 1]);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  end;
end;

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, length(chunkIndexArr), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, nil);
```

Code works as intended except I'm not sure is my normals arranged properly: they was stored as bytes (converted to GLfloat as b / FF), coordinates xyz changed and some probably need negation.

Can someone show me `geometry shader` to show normals as lines as shown at http://blogs.agi.com/insight3d/index.php/2008/10/23/geometry-shader-for-debugging-normals/ (those shader not works at all and it seems out/in data losed between vertex and fragment shader).

P.S. I'm not sure I did everything properly (starting OpenGL and GLSL) so any suggestions also appreciated.

Edit:
I made simple `geometry shader` by examples

```
// This is a very simple pass-through geometry shader
#version 330 core

layout (triangles) in;
layout (triangle_strip, max_vertices = 145) out;

in VS_GS_VERTEX
{
    vec2 UV;
    vec3 vs_worldpos;
    vec3 vs_normal;
} vertex_in[];

out GS_FS_VERTEX
{
    vec2 UV;
    vec3 vs_worldpos;
    vec3 vs_normal;
} vertex_out;

uniform float uNormalsLength = 0.5;

void main()
{
    int i;
    // Loop over the input vertices
    for (i = 0; i < gl_in.length(); i++)
    {
        vertex_out.UV = vertex_in[i].UV;
        vertex_out.vs_worldpos = vertex_in[i].vs_worldpos;
        vertex_out.vs_normal = vertex_in[i].vs_normal;

        // Copy the input position to the output
        gl_Position = gl_PositionIn[i];
        EmitVertex();

        gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * (gl_PositionIn[i] + (vec4(vertex_in[i].vs_normal, 0) * uNormalsLength));
        gl_FrontColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); //gl_FrontColorIn[i];
        EmitVertex();      
    }
    // End the primitive. This is not strictly necessary
    // and is only here for illustrative purposes.
    EndPrimitive();
}
```

but I don't knwo where it takes `gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix` (seems deprecated) and result looks awful, it seems everything including normals stripped. Picture in glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT, GL_LINE) mode, textures also trying to map onto those.
[image]

Comment: Why wouldn't that code work? It's perfectly simple. It passes normals from the application to the vertex shader and passes the normals through to the geomerty shader. In the GS, it simply generates a line segment using the vertex position and the offset vertex position, i.e. the vertex position translated some distance along the vertex normal, both transformed with the MVP matrix. That's it.

Comment: I can't figure how to make `geometry shader` for that. I made simple passthrough where I put out params from vs as `in` and put them as `out` but nothing shown at all (compiled without errors).

Comment: What's to figure out? The geometry shader code is right there on the page you linked. You can adapt that to GLSL 330 without any problems. Try that first and then come back with more specific questions. Or are you not sure how geometry shaders work at all?

Comment: Of course I'm not sure how everything works because I'm learning OpenGL several months so far. And everything there between "Hello world", outdated and deprecated. Every suggestions like "it is simple" through XXX without examples or examples with glBegin and shaders v130. I'll change with what make so far, but result awful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it seems, you're doing it all in a single pass and you actually emit 6 vertices per incoming triangle. This is not what you want.

Either do it in two passes, i.e. one pass for the mesh, the other for the normals, or try to emit the original triangle and a degenerate triangle for the normal. For simplicity I'd go for the two-pass version:

Inside your render loop:

- render terrain
- if and only if debug geometry is to be rendered

  - enable your debug normals shader
  - render the terrain mesh a second time, passing POINTS to the vertex shader

To make this work, you'll need a second program object that is made up like in the blog post you previously linked to, consisting of a simple pass trough vertex shader, the following geometry shader and a fragment shader for coloring the lines representing the normals.

The vertex and fragment shaders should be no problem. Assuming you have a smoothed mesh, i.e. you have actual, averaged vertex normals, you can simply pass in points and emit lines.

```
#version 330 core

// assuming you have vertex normals, you need to render a vertex
// only a single time. with any other prim type, you may render
// the same normal multiple times
layout (points) in; 

// Geometry shaders can only output points, line strips or triangle
// strips by definition. you output a single line per vertex. therefore, 
// the maximum number of vertices per line_strip is 2. This is effectively
// the same as rendering distinct line segments.
layout (line_strip, max_vertices = 2) out;

in      vec3  vs_normal[];
uniform float normal_scale = 0.5; // don't forget: this is the default value! 

/* if you're never going to change the normal_scale, consider simply putting a 
  constant there instead:
  const float normal_scale = 0.5;
*/

void main()
{
    // we simply transform and emit the incoming vertex - this is v0 of our
    // line segment
    vec4 v0     = gl_in[0].gl_Position;
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * v0;
    EmitVertex();

    // we calculate v1 of our line segment
    vec4 v1     = v0 + vec4(vs_normal[0] * normal_scale, 0);
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * v1;
    EmitVertex();

    EndPrimitive();
}
```

**Warning**: Untested code!

This is probably as simple as it gets. Add a uniform to your fragment shader so you can color your normals as you like or simply export a constant color.

**Note**: This code still uses gl_ModevelViewProjectionMatrix. If you're writing GL core code, please consider replacing legacy GL constructs, like the matrix stack, with your own stuff!

**Note 2**: Your geometry shader is **not** what is usually referred to as a pass through shader. First, you do processing on the incoming data that is more than just assigning incoming values to outgoing values. Second, how can it be a pass-through shader, if you generate geometry? Pass-through means, you don't do anything else than *pass* incoming values to the next shader stage.

Comment: Reading still. Not sure yet what is "If you're writing GL core code, please consider replacing legacy GL constructs" and where from `gl_ModevelViewProjectionMatrix` etc. I'm learning by "Addison Wesley - OpenGL Programming Guide 8th Edition" and there `core` in examples. But it seems I understand the idea and how it works much better now.

Comment: The 8th edition of the Red Book uses compatbility built-ins? See, the background is that there is no built-in variable gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix if you're really using a core context because it simply provided the product of the matrices which were at the top of the PROJECTION and MODELVIEW stacks (MVP = P * VM). If you have a compatibility context, this stuff is still available. If you want to be sure to only write core code, setup a core profile context. What Windowing toolkit do you use?

Comment: I making pure Delphi + OpenGL project and only header `dglOpenGL` to study what is OpenGL. Vertexes and other stuff from WoW's mpqs. Right now at terrain part.

Comment: Aside from the Red Book, read Jason McKesson's tutorial: http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Basics/Basics.html I know for a fact you're in good hands there. ;) Also, the OpenGL Wiki has a substantial amount of information, mainly written by the same author and some other: http://opengl.org/wiki